# GUI Issue: Don't Even Know Where to Begin

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel, jtextarea

I'm getting somewhere, but now I ran into an even bigger snag: I cannot seem to understand how to create a listener that changes the information on my JLabel to what is inputted and output information stored in my JTextArea.

Here is my code to give you an idea:

```
public class DisplayStudent extends JFrame {
private JMenuItem jmiConnect, jmiClose, jmiExit, jmiSearch, jmiClear;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JPanel contentPane2;
private JTextArea info;
private String information;

public JPanel contentPane() {
    JPanel something = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //something.setLayout();

    String information;

    info = new JTextArea(4, 30);
    info.setEditable(false);
    info.setLineWrap(true);
    info.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JPanel one = new JPanel();
    one.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    one.setSize(50, 50);
    one.add(info, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    something.add(one, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel two = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    two.setBackground(null);
    two.setSize(10, 10);
    two.add(new JLabel(" No Connection "), BorderLayout.WEST);
    two.add(new JLabel(" Number of Students = "), BorderLayout.EAST);
    something.add(two);

    something.setOpaque(true);
    return something;
}

public static void GUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Student");

    DisplayStudent panel = new DisplayStudent();
    frame.setContentPane(panel.contentPane());

    DisplayStudent bar = new DisplayStudent();
    frame.setJMenuBar(bar.DisplayStudent());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //frame.setJMenuBar(jmb);
}

public JMenuBar DisplayStudent() {
//Drop down menu
JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();

  JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
  fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');
  jmb.add(fileMenu);


  JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
  editMenu.setMnemonic('E');
  jmb.add(editMenu);

  //Buttons in menu - "File" menu
  JMenuItem jmiConnect = new JMenuItem("Connect", 'C');
  JMenuItem jmiClose = new JMenuItem("Close", 'L');
  JMenuItem jmiExit = new JMenuItem("Exit", 'E');

  fileMenu.add(jmiConnect); 
  fileMenu.add(jmiClose);
  fileMenu.add(jmiExit);

  //Buttons in menu - "Edit" menu
  JMenuItem jmiSearch = new JMenuItem("Search", 'S');
  JMenuItem jmiClear = new JMenuItem("Clear", 'B');

  editMenu.add(jmiSearch);
  editMenu.add(jmiClear);

  jmiConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String database_name;
         System.out.println("Please enter your database.");
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         database_name = input.next();
     }
  });

  jmiClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Question!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Toodleloo!");
    }
     }
  });

  jmiExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.exit(0);
     }
  });

  jmiSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.exit(0);
     }
  });

  jmiClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.exit(0);
     }
  });

  return jmb;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  GUI();

}
   }
```

I'm sorry for continue consulting. Reading isn't enough to get an understanding of this. I do appreciate your help once again everyone.

Okay, when I went back I got a pretty big error. Here it is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at displaystudent.DisplayStudent$1.actionPerformed(DisplayStudent.java:119)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:157)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I'm sorry if I am asking too much. I'm at my wits end now.

Comment: You could use a `DocumentListener` listener to monitor for changes to the `JTextArea`, this is little heavy handed and some more information about what you are trying to achieve would be helpful...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, I'm really sorry. What I'm trying to achieve is a program that has a few JMenuItems. One of the JMenuItems ("Connect") is suppose to ask for an input from the user then store that input under database_name and transfer the name out to the JLabel changing it from " No Connection " to " Connected to database_name " and also bring up info stored in a JTextArea.

Comment: So what's wrong with `JTextArea#appendText`?  You need to make the "connection" label an instance variable so you can access it when you need to

Comment: I don't see any database access code? What database are you trying t connect to?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmmmmm, well I tried something similar to that just now thinking I could set information, but it seems after I try and input the name of the pseudo database it blows up.

Comment: @peeskillet It's not a real database I'm trying to access. I apologize: I should have specified earlier. I'm creating a pseudo-database.

Comment: I don't even know what that means _"pseudo-database."_. Where is this data coming from?

Comment: @peeskillet I should just say a database in which I create a small amount of information for.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Uhm, well, I more than likely messed something up on the input area, so I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

> "transfer the name out to the JLabel changing it from " No Connection " to " Connected to database_name "

Problem: Your `JLabel` has no object reference. You're doing this

```
two.add(new JLabel(" No Connection "), BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Which makes *difficult* (not impossible) to get access to the `JLabel`. Instead give it a reference like

```
JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(" No Connection ");
public JPanel contentPane() {
    two.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Then you can access it from the `JMenuItem`'s listener.

```
jmiConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        statusLabel.setText(...);
    }
});
```

Here's another suggestion, don't try to mix console with GUI, i.e. `Scanner(System.in)`. You may want to use something like a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` or even a [`JCheckBoxMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) which is a check box in the menu with the database name that you can just check. Then it's just a matter of appending the result to the text area from the listener.

---

**UPDATE**

- Why are you creating a new `DisplayStudent` to put in the frame? Since the method returns a `JPanel` just do this

  ```
  JPanel panel = contentPane();
  frame.setContentPane(panel);
  ```
- Don't make your class extend `JFrame`. You are already using an instance of `JFrame` as your top-level container. Get rid of `extends JFrame`
- Don't call your method that returns the `JMenuBar` the same name as your class `DisplayStudent`. Call it something like `createMenuBar()`, then just do this

  ```
  JMenuMenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar();
  frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
  ```
- Get rid of both `DisplayStudent .. = new DisplayStudent();`

Comment: I appreciate it, friend. I went back and redid my JLabels and once I go back through and submit my input I got an error. A large one at that.

Comment: If I do that then I get an error telling me that it cannot invoke GUI() because I have to remove "Static." I'm sorry, I'm really new at this, so I'm sure I'm going to say something stupid. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @Zanpo take out the `static` from the `GUI` method. Then in the `main` just do `new DisplayStudent().GUI();`